# exist positive real numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $ (a_1, b_1)x^{a_1}y^{b_1} + (a_2, b_2)x^{a_2}y^{b_2} + \cdots + (a_n, b_n)x^{a_n}y^{b_n} = (0, 0)$

Tags: real-analysis, contest-math

Problem Statement: Let $(a_1, b_1), (a_2, b_2),...,(a_n, b_n)$ be the vertices of a convex polygon which contains the origin in its interior. Prove that there exist positive real numbers $x$ and $y$ such that
\begin{equation}
    (a_1, b_1)x^{a_1}y^{b_1} + (a_2, b_2)x^{a_2}y^{b_2} + \cdots + (a_n, b_n)x^{a_n}y^{b_n} = (0, 0)
\end{equation}

I know that because $(a_1, b_1), (a_2, b_2),...,(a_n, b_n)$ is vertices of convex polygon, at least one of the $a_i$ and one of the $b_i$ is negative and at least one of them is positive as well. The terms with negative $a_i$, $b_i$ go to $-\infty$ as either x or y go to $0$, which the positive ones go to $\infty$ as either x or y go to infinity. I'm thinking of invoking intermediate value theorem from here but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Find a family of lines through the origin, along which to invoke the IVT.  Then the actual IVT is quite easy (for the first coordinate).  Then, look at this family at one end of the polygon, and at the other.  Invoke the IVT for the other coordinate.